# Installing OpenCV on Windows 10 for Python 3

Tags: python, windows, opencv, python-3.x

I've downloaded and extracted OpenCV from the official website. I've learnt from [this page](http://opencv.org/opencv-3-0.html) that OpenCV 3 has Python 3 support, so my question is, why is there only the `2.7/` directory under the `[opencv]/build/python/` directory??? Why isn't there a directory for Python 3?

Obviously, the `cv2.pyd` files in the `2.7/x64/` and `2.7/x86/` directories do not work with Python 3, but they do work with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to install opencv via pip 
`pip install opencv-python`

Answer (score 0):

USING opncv310 , ON vc2010 , WIN10 Home.
My software  was working find until January 17 , and stop working ( most of the Open CV functions crash) .

I tried other several  PCs with win 7 and win 10 Pro , The same exe and dlls  working find.
I tried other PC with win 10 Home , didn't work too.

So, my conclusion is that in January WIN 10 Home did some UPDATE that made OPENCV to fail.